# Некорректно работает форма, игнорируется знак вопроса

Tags: html, form

Есть форма

```
<form name="Москва Адлер туда обратно" action='https://site.ru/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&with_request=true' target="_blank"><input  type="submit" value="Перейти"></form>
```

Проблема в том, что знак `?` в урл не воспринимается и весь урл обрезается после вопроса. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно обойти?

Comment: Использовать input type=hidden

Comment: Если ты отправляешь данные на апи, то попробуй при отправке формы делать `event.preventDefault()`, формировать url в коде и отправлять ajax. Это если уж совсем ничего не поможет.

Comment: @Alexey Ten Если hidden, то кнопки видно не будет

Comment: @Данил Скрипник Не получается

Comment: Не восприниматься может в двух случаях, на вскидку:

Comment: Убрал форму у инпута тип button сделал, заработало